# How to find current limit or resistance of current path that is a polygon in PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, trace

I'm trying to understand what is the relevant path of current when I use polygons for PCB design.

*Edit: I'm particularly interested in the current limit in that path without destroying it. Please ignore the thermal reliefs. I'll be removing them soon.*

So in this example, I would like to know the current limits for the path connecting the two points of node A. I know the height of the copper, I'm assuming the length would be a straight line connecting them. But what is the "width" here?

[image]

Also, how different is the answer to above if the shape is not so nice. i.e. : 
[image]

Examples/explanations using pictures would be appreciated.

I'm using Altium designer. Is there a built-in tool from there to do measure current limit or resistance between two contacts?

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to know the current limits for the path connecting the two points of node A"? The copper will have a resistance. The largest resistance comes from the 'thermal relief' connection around the two holes (both labelled A). I am not an Altium user, but the dimensions of the thermal relief connection from the (plated) hole to the copper polygon is normally under your control, and hence you can adjust its resistance.

Comment: In the circuit schematic (ideal), both are meant to be the same point; so I labeled them same. I'll replace thermal relief with direct connection. Is there any disadvantage to that btw?

Comment: The reason for thermal reliefs is to make soldering easier (or possible).  Without thermals you need to pump in enough energy to heat up the entire plane of copper before the solder flows in a nice way.  With thermals, the plated through holes can get considerably hotter than the surrounding copper.

Comment: As I wrote, I'd expect Altium to be able to control the dimensions of thermal relief. So you can adjust the resistance of the thermal relief. As mentioned by bitsmack, removing all thermal relief so that pads are fully connected to the copper polygon, could make through-hole parts harder to solder with a soldering iron. So if you are making the board by hand, using a soldering iron, it may be better to widen the thermal relief paths to reduce resistance rather than remove them completely.

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate the resistance due to the thermal reliefs, and the resistance due to the vias (if you want to include the vias in the path under consideration). The resistance due to the polygon will be negligible compared to these resistances.

If you want to figure out the contribution of the polygon anyway, first figure out the surface resistance of your copper, in ohms per square (You'll find that the resistance between opposite edges of a square of copper sheet will be equal, regardless of the size of the square). Then break up the polygon roughly into squares between the two vias. Then figure out the resistance between the two vias in terms of series and parallel combinations of copper squares.

Or, if you want a more accurate result, you'll need to resort to a finite elements model. This can also account for "spreading resistance" around the vias.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm more concerned with the current limit where it'll melt/smoke. How do I calculate the area that's current passing through?

Comment: Again, worry about the thermal reliefs and the vias before you worry about the polygon.

Comment: If you really want to know, "1 ounce" copper is 35 um thick. If these are outer layers, you should also account for any plating (typically adds another 1/2 ounce).

Comment: @Photon, We don't plan on having thermal reliefs. It's at a point where I'm just trying to judge the floor plan so everything's at default configuration yet, that's why it's in the pic. Sorry about that